# I am using cordova-plugin-facebook4 in my nativescript app. When I build the application, it is showing the variables APP_ID and APP_NAME are missing

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, nativescript, facebook-analytics, nativescript-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe7sx.png)I want to log the App Events of my application in Facebook analytics. My App is built on NativeScript. I could not find a plugin to log the events in facebook analytics. So, I am using cordova-plugin-facebook4 to log app events. But the project is not building.

Comment: Did you update the cordova plugin's `config.xml` file with APP_ID and APP_NAME?

Comment: Actually I am using cordova plugin in nativescript application. So, I could not find the config.xml file anywhere in my project. The project is a nativescript project.   Once check the following links:                  https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-use-any-cordova-plugin-with-nativescript                                                                                     https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cordova-support

Comment: Do you have a repo which we can quickly clone and see this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove and reinstall the plugin with the following command

```
 cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="YOUR_APP_ID" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

Comment: my project is not a cordova application. It is a nativescript application. But I did not find any plugin that can implement AppEventsLogger functionality of the Facebook Android SDK. So, I am trying to use cordova plugin.